# Not getting newlines in output when using PHP_EOL

Tags: php

I am putting together a string that I will output to a .srt file:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $srt = $srt . $row['line_number'] . PHP_EOL; 
    $srt = $srt . str_replace(".", ",", $row['start']) . " --> " . str_replace(".", ",", $row['end']) .PHP_EOL ;    
    $srt = $srt . br2nl($row['text']) . PHP_EOL; 
    $srt = $srt . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

But it seems like `PHP_EOL` isn't working, because my output is:

```
100:00:02,107 --> 00:00:05,810you sure
```

and doesn't have any newlines. I am trying to get my output to be:

```
1
00:00:02,107 --> 00:00:05,810
you sure
```

followed by a newline.

It works when testing through localhost on my computer. Could the PHP version on my host be missing support for `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: Are you sure you want an actual End Of Line and not a <br />?

Comment: Is your server on a linux and you open the file in windows?

Comment: DXL i've tried to use <br/> but in .srt file it look just <br/>

Comment: Muse iam using Wampserver on windows it works good

Comment: but on my online website it doesn't

Comment: are trying to open the file generated on your online server which is probably running linux on windows?

Comment: haynar on the code  above the output goes to an .srt file and when i download the srt file the file is without newlines

Answer (score 8):

The PHP manual says the PHP_EOL constant was available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

> PHP_EOL (string)
>       The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2 - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

So test to see if it exists:

```
var_dump(PHP_EOL); // should output: string(1) " "
```

OR

```
var_dump(defined("PHP_EOL")); // should output if exists: bool(true)
```

and if it is not defined, just define it manually if you want

```
define("PHP_EOL", "\n");
```

OR just use `echo "\n"` or `echo "\r\n"`

The other possible reason is when you output the `$srt` variable in your browser your outputting and the mime type is set in HTML and so you see it as one line, but if you view the source it should be spanned accross multiple lines.

To ensure text output you could echo out a `<pre>` tag if you want to keep html or at the top of your php file add this line to force text output:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain', true);
```

Comment: so i tried to use var_dump(PHP_EOL);
and it didn't give any output?
on my localhost the output is (true)

Comment: So it's not defined on your server. Try to just use "\n" in stead of PHP_EOL. Example: `$srt = $srt . $row['line_number'] . "\n"; `

Answer (score 1):

> PHP_EOL The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.

So it works on local host because its window and gives a windows line break

You online website is probably on linux and gives a linux line-break

To get a consistent result use `"\r\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL`, although I think media players will be a ble to recognize any style of line breaks.